# Namespace of mshtml.tlb has inexplicably changed from lowercase to uppercase

Tags: c#, msbuild, mshtml

I have a range of c# projects which have compiled happily for a number of years. I've recently been trying t reference MSHTML on a build machine. To do this I grabbed the TLB files from System32 and SysWOW64 and referenced them using a ComFileReference via 'tlbimp'.

Now my program won't compile, lots of errors of the form Namespace 'mshtml' does not exist.

I've worked out that the namespace is now called MSHTML, when and why did it change?

Is there a correct way to reference this DLL such that the namespace is lower case again.

This has gotten a little more serious since code we purchased from elsewhere is now exhibiting the problem without my having tinkered with the project files, and it's been fine for a number of releases for around 5 years.

I'm really not sure what's happened. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Mark

Answer (score 2):

I worked out what I did wrong, and if anybody else has this inexplicable problem, then this is the answer:

When you reference mshtml.dll via the Primary Interop Assemblies distributed with Visual studio, the assembly namespace is *Lower* case.

If you try and create your own interop by using tlbimp with the default options, then the assembly namespace is *Upper* case.

In c# this is annoying, but I guess that Microsoft did that so that you know what you did wrong (provided that you already know why the case changes).

I hope this saves some time for somebody.

Mark